# How to realize wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS and wx.lib.intctrl.IntCtrl in PySide?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, pyside

I'm working on a well-working program which is written in wxpython. I need to rewrite it using PySide. So I need to find replacement commands in PySide.

```
self.tc.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.HelpMessages(field))
```

This is one of the problems I met. I know it means an event, when something gets the focus by a mouse click, it triggers `self.HelpMessages`. But which command in PySide can get a similar effect? Similarly, is there any command that can replace the lost focus like below?

```
self.tc.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.OnKillFocus)
```

Another problem I have to deal with is this one.

```
self.tc = wx.lib.intctrl.IntCtrl(self.parent, -1, field[con.ConfigFields.VALUE], pos=(x+220, y-3), size=(200, -1), allow_none=True)
```

Based on the documentation `wx.lib.inctrl.IntCtrl` provides a control that takes and returns integers as value, and provides bounds support and optional value limiting.

So does PySide has a similar function?

I know these two questions are fragmentary. It's really kind of you if you can give some examples to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest approach would be to search for focus events in PyQt. PySide is just a port of PyQt, so you just need to change the imports slightly to make most examples in PyQt work for PySide. Anyway, I found the following link:

- [PyQt window focus events not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377397/pyqt-window-focus-events-not-called)

I believe all you need to do is call QMainWindow's setFocusPolicy and connect the following signal:

```
QObject.connect(app, SIGNAL("focusChanged(QWidget *, QWidget *)"), changedFocusSlot)
```

Then you should be able to detect focus events.